# Use of tokens in Django for validation in URLs

Tags: django, token

I need to e-mail visitors (not registered users) a link to view a page on my website. The page will have an ID that corresponds to a certain record in the database. However, I would like to ensure that the users indeed got the link from the e-mail and didn't just manually enter a database ID. To do so, adding a token to the URL seems a good way to go. Unless I have to, I prefer to NOT store additional information (the token) in the database, but instead use the existing ID to create the token (using some sort of a salt), and re-generate the token based on the ID and check if this is valid.

My question is: what is a good way to generate this token in Django? Is it a good idea to use the [make_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password) function? Or do I use say [SHA1](https://www.pythoncentral.io/hashing-strings-with-python/#custom-tab-0-python-3-x) encryption of the string? What trade-offs should I take into account and is there a specific route that would be preferred for this situation?

Comment: If you don't store the token, you will have to compare something from the URL to your DB. I have a similar thing in my project. I store the token and then compare it.

Comment: Yes the idea is to use the ID in the URL and compare that to the token. The ID is already stored in the db. If I really must, I can also store the token, but it seems overkill in this case.

Comment: But how would you know to who the token belongs to, you would have to hash out all the ids from the DB on the spot and wait for a match if you don't store the token

Comment: This system is not related to validating users. All I want to make sure is that people that open the links have access to the original email (and thus also have the token). I want to avoid that people manually enter a different ID and also have access to different records.

Comment: I understand, you want certain info on specific ID or TOKEN of ID loaded from link in email. And prevent a user from changing the ID and getting other info. I really think you will need to store the token somewhere to confirm it and load specific info,

Comment: Please do post as an answer if you believe that is the best way to go. But I also believe I can get a SHA hash from the ID and simply compare that... that wouldn't require any additional storage. But if there are reasons for storing the token in the db, by all means elaborate and let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the TOKEN you create from encrypting the ID because there won't be a way for the system to find the corresponding ID to the TOKEN when the link in the email is loaded.

The only way to find the ID that corresponds to the token would be to brute force hash every ID when the view loads and compare the TOKENs to find the one that corresponds. This is not efficient at all.

The encrypted TOKEN you create for the ID will always be the same, so it's a kind of safe way of preventing unwanted visitors with out authentication.

BTW, I actually have a similar method in one of my systems. The TOKEN must be stored.

Here's an example of how I create the tokens.

```
import hashlib

def encrypt_string(id_string):
   
   sha_signature = hashlib.sha1(id_string.encode()).hexdigest()
   
   return sha_signature
```

Comment: Thanks - but could you also address the main premise of the question: how do I generate the token? make_passwords? SHA1 encryption? What are trade-offs between these various mechanisms? Thanks